# UART_getc() does not work correctly with newline character

Tags: c, input, output, uart

I am trying to write some basic i/O functions: UART_getc, UART_putc, UART_gets and UART_puts. UART_getc and putc work well until I input a new line character. Instead of a normal newline (cursor is at the most left of the line), it makes a new line and a white space behind it so the cursor is at the middle of the screen(picture)
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scco9.jpg)
Could you show me what's wrong with my code and how to fix it?

```
    #include <uart.h>

    // ======================================================================

    #define IO_READ(addr)           (*(volatile unsigned int *)(addr))
    #define IO_WRITE(addr, val)     (*(volatile unsigned int *)(addr) = (val))

    // ======================================================================

    #define UART1_RHR_REG   0x44e09000      // UART1 Receive holding register
    #define UART1_THR_REG   0x44e09000      // UART1 Transmit holding register
    #define UART1_LSR_REG   0x44e09014      // UART1 Line status register

    #define LSR_RX_FIFO_E   0x01    // LSR receive fifo empty
    #define LSR_TX_FIFO_E   0x20    // LSR transmit fifo empty

    // ======================================================================

    int UART_getc(void)
    {
    unsigned int c;

    while((IO_READ(UART1_LSR_REG) & LSR_RX_FIFO_E) == 0);  //if fifo is 
                                                           //empty, wait

    c = IO_READ(UART1_RHR_REG);                            //if not empty

    UART_putc(c);

    return (int)c;
    }
    //====================================================================
    int UART_putc(int c)
    {
    while(IO_READ(UART1_LSR_REG) & (LSR_TX_FIFO_E) == 0);  //if fifo is 
                                                           //full, wait

    IO_WRITE(UART1_THR_REG, c);                            //if not full

    return c;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible you're getting CRLF (DOS-style) line endings instead of NL or LF (Unix-style) line endings?  The "space" you'd be seeing would be a CR (carriage return) under this hypothesis.

Comment: Can you log what actual characters you are receiving? It's entirely possible (in fact, likely) that whatever is talking to your UART is not sending the line ending characters that you are expecting and you will need to write code to translate whatever you are receiving into whatever your terminal expects. (But we have no idea what you're receiving and we have no idea what your terminal expects either.)

Comment: you are right. It is carriage return character, not line feed. This code is ok but the problem was in my test code. I have solved this problem by replacing \n by \r\n.